# handler problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a handler which apply watermark to all images from a folder. I declared in web.config:

```
<add verb="GET" type="ImageWatermarkHandler" path="Item/*.jpg,Item/*.png"/>
```

On localhost it works but when I put it online it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,
Alina

Comment: add verb="GET" type="ImageWatermarkHandler" path="Item/*.jpg,Item/*.png"

Comment: Please remember to click on {} icon after selecting your code sample. Otherwise it might be invisible. Also, you have post preview below text box; use it to see how your question will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS7 the HttpHandler declaration is supposed to go in the web.server section. In IIS6 it's inside the system.web.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx) on registering HttpHandlers.

Comment: and Visual Studio development server is using system.web

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<add verb="GET" type="ImageWatermarkHandler" path="~/Item/*.jpg, ~/Item/*.png" />
```

Comment: Do you use the tildes too (to specify the root of the application)?

Comment: If the relative/absolute path is not the problem, maybe you should check the configuration of IIS on localhost vs. production.

Comment: On localhost I have IIS 6 and on production I have IIS 7, this can this be a problem?

Comment: It's more likely that both IIS servers are configured differently -- if so, then you cannot know whether something is going to work on production simply by testing it in development. You need the same configuration on your dev machine as on production.